# objective-c , Finding objects from array

Tags: objective-c

I have an array that contains some objects;
example:
 **NSArray*arr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@5,@7,@6 nil];**

How I could find, for example if the array contains the number 1 and 7 without creating a loop.
Is there such a function?
For example returns a Boolean value or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing!
You can use this method

- (BOOL)containsObject:(ObjectType)anObject;

or somethings else:

- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(ObjectType)anObject;
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(ObjectType)anObject inRange:(NSRange)range;

Have fun.

Comment: I used at the end in (BOOL) containsObject: (ObjectType) anObject;

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOfObject to find if an element is present in your array or not :

```
NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:7];
NSInteger anIndex=[myArray indexOfObject:num];
if(NSNotFound == anIndex) {
    NSLog(@"not found");
}
```

Hope this helps.